# get Grand parent Django

Tags: python, django, parent

im working in something like this on Django:
the MODELS has this structure.

```
Category
  - name
  - parent category
```

And i was wondering if is posible to get the main parent (grand parent) in one only query. like:

```
Category.objects.get(pk = 10, absolutefirstoneofall)
```

for an example i got this.

```
Computers
 - Laptops
   - branch
     - seller
```

if i get a seller, i want to now the main category as well. this data are not for real is just an example.

Thanks for you support friends.

Comment: Can you show us a little more of the models? I'm not sure I understood the structure there

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to implement a tree in the database in the "adjacency list" form. You might want to look at the [treebeard](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard) library, which is designed to handle the ugly details for you.

You might also want to look at the "nested set" form of trees, which generally perform better than adjacency lists when reads vastly outnumber writes, and can easily and quickly do things like "get this node and all its children" in one DB query.

```
from treebeard import NSNode

class Category(NSNode):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # ...
```

To get all the root nodes:

```
Category.get_root_nodes()
```

returns `[<Category: Computers>]`

To get a list of the ancestors of a node:

```
Category.objects.get(name="seller").get_ancestors()
```

returns `[<Category: branch>, <Category: Laptops>, <Category: Computers>]`

To get the root node of the tree that has a given node:

```
Category.objects.get(name="seller").get_root()
```

returns `<Category: Computers>`